# I can't load webfont

Tags: css, webfonts

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Han Sans;
    src: url(http://before-the-dawn.com/spoqa-han-sans/han-sans-regular.woff2) format('woff2'),
        url(http://before-the-dawn.com/spoqa-han-sans/han-sans-regular.woff) format('woff'),
        url(http://before-the-dawn.com/spoqa-han-sans/han-sans-regular.ttf) format('truetype');
    font-weight: 500;
    }
```

I uploaded some font files onto my webhosting, and trying to load it as webfont. But it seems that I can't use theese, and I can't even know why..

Comment: what errors does your developer console give you? i bet `Han Sans` not being quoted isnt helping.

Comment: I also tried with 'Han Sans' as font family name, but nothing changed.

Comment: There's an error message on console, "blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: is the page you are working on also on that domain? wherever you are hosting the fonts is not set up to allow users from other domains to consume its assets/resources.

Comment: Thanks. I changed hosting server and it works fine now.

Answer (score -1):

If this is an Adobe font, make sure you have your permissions are correctly set on the Typekit site.